# Rewriting a system of two equations found in The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis (A. Turing, 1952)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

In reading [The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis](https://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf)
 by A. Turing, I am unable to follow a small section of his working. On page $47$, Turing states that

\begin{align*} x_r&=\sum_{s=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi
irs}{N}\right)\xi_s, \\ y_r&=\sum_{s=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi
irs}{N}\right)\eta_s, \end{align*}

can be written as

\begin{align*} \xi_r&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{s=1}^{N} \exp\left(-\frac{2\pi
irs}{N}\right)x_s, \\ \eta_r&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{s=1}^{N} \exp\left(-\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)y_s. \end{align*}

This does not seem obvious to me. It is given that this can be shown by using the equations
\begin{align}
\sum_{s=1}^N \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)&=0 \ \ \text{if} \ \ 0<r<N, \\
&=N \ \ \text{if} \ \ r=0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ r=N.
\end{align}
However, I do not see how this helps. I hint would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sums for $x_s$ and $y_s$
in the sums for $\xi$ and $\eta$
and then reverse the order of summation.

Use those last sums to make almost everything go to zero except the desired terms.

Comment: Ideally I would like to derive the sums for $\xi$ and $\eta$ without using said sums in my working out. That is, how can I begin with say the sum $x_s$ to derive (using the hint provided by Turing) the sum for $\xi$?